# Solve the differential eqution $y'=\frac{y}{4x+2y^2\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential eqution $y'=\frac{y}{4x+2y^2\sqrt{x}}$

My attempt:

i have chosen $y^2=t \implies 2yy'=t'$

then $t'=\frac{t}{x+2t\sqrt{x}}$

but I am not getting anything

any other idea of this problem

Comment: try $$\int y(x) y’(x) dx=\frac{y^2}{2}+c$$

Comment: @TymaGaidash..sorry i am not getting your point

Comment: You have $2yy’=t’$, so you can integrate both sides.

Comment: @TymaGaidash..what's the purpose of doing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation is   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{4x+2y^2\sqrt{x}},$$
wich is equivalent to
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{4x+2y^2\sqrt{x}}{y}=\frac{4}{y}x+2y\sqrt{x}.$$
This is a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) for $x$. If you write in this way:
$$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{4}{y}x=2y\sqrt{x},$$
divide both sides by $\sqrt{x}$ and make the substitution $v=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x}$
, you get a linear equation for $v$.

Edit: I will write down the complete solution.
$$x^{-1/2}\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{4}{y}\sqrt{x}=2y,$$
by doing $v=\sqrt{x}$ we get that $v'=\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}x'$, where the derivatives are with respect to y. So, inserting in the equation:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{dv}{dy}-\frac{4}{y}v=2y.$$
Using the integrating factor method we find
$$v=Cy^8-\frac{2}{3}y^2,$$
that is
$$\sqrt{x}=Cy^8-\frac{2}{3}y^2$$

Comment: Plus there's the solution $y=0$.

Comment: thank you sir.. i tried the way but i lost somewhere